# @ManyToOne with JOIN FetchMode generating inner join

Tags: java, hibernate, join

Reading all the documentation, using @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN) on a @ManyToOne should by default I believe generate a left outer join, but for me it is always generating an inner join. These are my beans:

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;

/**
* PensionMember entity. @author MyEclipse Persistence Tools
*/
@Entity
@Table(name = "Z_PENSION_MEMBERS", schema = "DANAOS")
public class PensionMember implements java.io.Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = -4541446336298304689L;

   // Fields

   private Long id;
   private Long personsCode;
   private String employeeCode;
   private String personType;
   private CrewOfficeEmployee employee;
   private PersonTO person;

   // Property accessors
   @Id
   @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 0)
   public Long getId() {
      return this.id;
   }

   public void setId(Long id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_CODE", length = 12)
   public String getEmployeeCode() {
      return this.employeeCode;
   }

   public void setEmployeeCode(String employeeCode) {
      this.employeeCode = employeeCode;
   }

   @ManyToOne( cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, optional=true )
   @JoinColumn( name = "EMPLOYEE_CODE", insertable = false, updatable = false )
   @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
   public CrewOfficeEmployee getEmployee(){
      return employee;
   }

   public void setEmployee( CrewOfficeEmployee employee ){
      this.employee = employee;
   }

   @Column(name = "PERSONS_CODE", precision = 126, scale = 0, insertable = false, updatable = false)
   public Long getPersonsCode() {
       return this.personsCode;
   }

   public void setPersonsCode(Long personsCode) {
       this.personsCode = personsCode;
   }

   @ManyToOne( cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, optional=true )
   @JoinColumn( name = "PERSONS_CODE" )
   @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
   public PersonTO getPerson() {
       return person;
   }

   public void setPerson(PersonTO person) {
       this.person = person;
   }

   @Column(name = "PERSON_TYPE", nullable = false, length = 1)
   public String getPersonType() {
       return this.personType;
   }

   public void setPersonType(String personType) {
       this.personType = personType;
   }
}

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;

/**
* CrewOfficeEmployee entity. @author MyEclipse Persistence Tools
*/
@Entity
@Table(name = "Z_CREW_OFFICE_EMPLOYEES", schema = "DANAOS")
public class CrewOfficeEmployee implements java.io.Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = -5900130959401376537L;

   // Fields

   private String id;
   private Integer crewOfficeJobTitleId;
   private String name;
   private String surname;
   private Date dateOfBirth;
   private Date effectiveJoiningDate;
   private Date joiningDate;
   private Date leavingDate;

   // Property accessors
   @Id
   @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 12)
   public String getId() {
      return this.id;
   }

   public void setId(String id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   @Column(name = "JOB_TITLE_ID", nullable = false)
   public Integer getCrewOfficeJobTitleId() {
      return crewOfficeJobTitleId;
   }

   public void setCrewOfficeJobTitleId(Integer crewOfficeJobTitleId) {
      this.crewOfficeJobTitleId = crewOfficeJobTitleId;
   }

   @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 30)
   public String getName() {
      return this.name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   @Column(name = "SURNAME", nullable = false, length = 30)
   public String getSurname() {
      return this.surname;
   }

   public void setSurname(String surname) {
      this.surname = surname;
   }

   @Column(name = "DATE_OF_BIRTH", nullable = false, length = 7)
   public Date getDateOfBirth() {
      return this.dateOfBirth;
   }

   public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
      this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
   }

   @Column(name = "EFFECTIVE_JOINING_DATE", nullable = false, length = 7)
   public Date getEffectiveJoiningDate() {
      return this.effectiveJoiningDate;
   }

   public void setEffectiveJoiningDate(Date effectiveJoiningDate) {
      this.effectiveJoiningDate = effectiveJoiningDate;
   }

   @Column(name = "JOINING_DATE", nullable = false, length = 7)
   public Date getJoiningDate() {
      return this.joiningDate;
   }

   public void setJoiningDate(Date joiningDate) {
      this.joiningDate = joiningDate;
   }

   @Column(name = "LEAVING_DATE", length = 7)
   public Date getLeavingDate() {
      return this.leavingDate;
   }

   public void setLeavingDate(Date leavingDate) {
      this.leavingDate = leavingDate;
   }
}
```

This is my query:

```
Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(PensionMember.class);
crit.createAlias("employee", "employee");
crit.createAlias("person", "person");
crit.add(
    Restrictions.or(
        Restrictions.and(
            Restrictions.eq( PERSON_TYPE, "V" ),
            Restrictions.like( "person.personsSurname", surname, MatchMode.START ).ignoreCase()
        ),
        Restrictions.and(
            Restrictions.eq( PERSON_TYPE, "O" ),
            Restrictions.like( "employee.surname", surname, MatchMode.START ).ignoreCase()
        )
    )
);
```

... and this is the resulting SQL:

```
select * from ( select this_.ID as ID23020_6_, this_.EMPLOYEE_CODE as EMPLOYEE3_23020_6_, this_.PERSONS_CODE as PERSONS7_23020_6_, 
this_.PERSON_TYPE as PERSON6_23020_6_, employee1_.ID as ID23010_0_, employee1_.JOB_TITLE_ID as JOB2_23010_0_, 
employee1_.DATE_OF_BIRTH as DATE3_23010_0_, employee1_.EFFECTIVE_JOINING_DATE as EFFECTIVE4_23010_0_, 
employee1_.JOINING_DATE as JOINING5_23010_0_, employee1_.LEAVING_DATE as LEAVING6_23010_0_, 
employee1_.NAME as NAME23010_0_, employee1_.SURNAME as SURNAME23010_0_,  person2_.STATUS_CODE as STATUS2_22758_1_, etc
from DANAOS.Z_PENSION_MEMBERS this_ 
inner join DANAOS.Z_CREW_OFFICE_EMPLOYEES employee1_ on this_.EMPLOYEE_CODE=employee1_.ID 
inner join PERSONS person2_ on this_.PERSONS_CODE=person2_.PERSONS_CODE 
where ((this_.PERSON_TYPE=? and lower(person2_.PERSONS_SURNAME) like ?) or 
(this_.PERSON_TYPE=? and lower(employee1_.SURNAME) like ?)) ) where rownum <= ?
```

How come?! Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
Neil

I'm using Hibernate 3.6.10 btw

Comment: Can you provide the DDL of your Z_PENSION_MEMBERS table ?

Answer (score 2):

Having realised it was the criteria query that was the problem, the solution was to change the createAlias() methods:

```
Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(PensionMember.class);
crit.createAlias("employee", "employee", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);
crit.createAlias("person", "person", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);
```

Comment: Thanks but that form of the createAlias method is deprecated in Hibernate 5, instead use this:    criteria.createAlias("person", "person", org.hibernate.sql.JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);

Answer (score 0):

```
@ManyToOne( cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, optional=true )
@JoinColumn( name = "EMPLOYEE_CODE", insertable = false, updatable = false )
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)    
public CrewOfficeEmployee getEmployee(){
   return employee;
}
```

first of all change "insertable = false" to true.

I am getting(left outer join) :

Hibernate:

> select this_.ID as ID1_1_1_, this_.EMPLOYEE_CODE1 as EMPLOYEE3_1_1_,
>   this_.EMPLOYEE_CODE as EMPLOYEE2_1_1_, crewoffice2_.ID as ID1_0_0_,
>   crewoffice2_.JOB_TITLE_ID as JOB_TITL2_0_0_,
>   crewoffice2_.DATE_OF_BIRTH as DATE_OF_3_0_0_,
>   crewoffice2_.EFFECTIVE_JOINING_DATE as EFFECTIV4_0_0_,
>   crewoffice2_.JOINING_DATE as JOINING_5_0_0_, crewoffice2_.LEAVING_DATE
>   as LEAVING_6_0_0_, crewoffice2_.NAME as NAME7_0_0_,
>   crewoffice2_.SURNAME as SURNAME8_0_0_ from Z_PENSION_MEMBERS this_
>   left outer join Z_CREW_OFFICE_EMPLOYEES crewoffice2_ on
>   this_.EMPLOYEE_CODE1=crewoffice2_.ID order by this_.ID asc

I think your code should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It made me realise that it was the query that was the problem not the mapping. A findById() provides an outer join, but the query I was running (see edited question) still creates an inner join